# React Native: Getting data from one class to another

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, react-native, reactive-programming

CLASS 1

```
import moment from "moment";
import InfoScreen from "./InfoScreen";

export default class LaunchingScreen extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      dataSource: null,
      refreshing: false
    };
  }

//When screen is pulled down this calls for fresh through the state its int

  _onRefresh = () => {
    this.setState({ refreshing: true });
    this.componentDidMount().then(() => {
      this.setState({ refreshing: false });
    });
  };


//Gets data from API 

  componentDidMount() {
    return fetch("https://launchlibrary.net/1.4/launch?mode=verbose")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          dataSource: responseJson.launches
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }


//Renders Screen

  render() {
    //Refresh if statement
    if (this.state.isLoading) {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <ActivityIndicator />
        </View>
      );
    } else {
      let date = moment().format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY"); //Gets today's date via moment library

        //Launches is what its called on later to display what is being said in launches
        let launches = this.state.dataSource.map((item, key) => {

        //Location of Launch
        let Location = item.location.name;

        //Date of launch formated 
        let LaunchDate = moment(item.isostart, moment.ISO_8601).format("llll");
        return (
          <View key={key} style={styles.container}>
            <Image
              style={{ width: 350, height: 475, borderRadius: 10 }}
              source={{ uri: item.rocket.imageURL }}
            />

          //WHERE USER TABS TO GET MORE INFO 

            <TouchableHighlight
              onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("InfoScreen")}
            >
              <View style={styles.subcontainer}>
                <Text style={{ paddingBottom: 3 }}>
                  <Text style={styles.TextHeader}>Launch Date: </Text>
                  <Text style={styles.Text}>{LaunchDate}</Text>
                </Text>
                <Text style={{ paddingBottom: 3 }}>
                  <Text style={styles.TextHeader}>Location: </Text>
                  <Text style={styles.Text}>{Location}</Text>
                </Text>
                <Text style={{ paddingBottom: 3 }}>
                  <Text style={styles.TextHeader}>Service Provider: </Text>
                  <Text style={styles.Text}>{item.lsp.name}</Text>
                </Text>
                <Text style={{ paddingBottom: 3 }}>
                  <Text style={styles.TextHeader}>Rocket: </Text>
                  <Text style={styles.Text}>{item.rocket.name}</Text>
                </Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableHighlight>
          </View>
        );
      });

      //Allows the screen to be scrollable w/ refresh control 
      return (
        <View style={styles.Background}>

          <ScrollView
            contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}
            refreshControl={
              <RefreshControl
                refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
                onRefresh={this._onRefresh}
              />
            }
          >
            <View style={styles.dateContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.dateText}>{date}</Text>
            </View>


            {launches}
          </ScrollView>


        </View>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

CLASS 2

```
import Location from "./LaunchingScreen.js";

export default class InfoScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (

        <View>
        <Text>hugig</Text>

        </View>



    );
  }
}
```

[image: Rocket "card"]
[image: info screen]
Ok I'm going to try to explain this as best I can.The app basically displays when, where, etc. a rocket launch is happening in a form of a "card" displayed in the pictures. Im using react native and what I want to do is make it so when someone taps on the touchableHighlight (rocket launch "card") it takes them from Class 1 to class 2. Class 2 is where the info of whatever rocket launch "card"  the user tapped is displayed. The problem Im having is getting the data from the specific rocket launch the user pressed to class 2/ info screen. Ive tried exporting the method that gets the name, date, etc. but that didn't work.

Comment: Where are you mounting those components? I guess you got an `App` component right?

Comment: Which navigator are you using?

Comment: Im using the react nativgation and they are in app.js file

Comment: @NoeDuran did you tried my answer?

Comment: @HaiderAli just got back home, im going to try it not and see how it goes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to pass navigation params like this

```
this.props.navigation.navigate("InfoScreen", {
              itemId: 86,
              otherParam: 'anything you want here',
            })
```

Then use these params in the other screen like this

```
const { itemId, otherParam } = this.props.navigation.state.params
```

You can learn more [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/params.html) about passing the params.

Comment: I could try a book about how thankful I am, this problem halted this project, dude, you're amazing